# How add a dot before of word "com" in a email address?

Tags: delphi, email-validation

So,

I have a large txt file that contains several email address, and some email address are without a dot before word "com" and now I want add this string in all invalids email address before save to file.

For example some email address are in this format:

*aaglt_assessoria@yahoocom.br*

where correct way should be:

*aaglt_assessoria@yahoo.com.br*

and my code about how I'm saving theses emails:

```
function ExtractEmails(const Input: String; out Emails: TStringList): Boolean;
var
  I, position : Integer;
  Buffer : String;
  Tokens : TStringList;
begin
  Result := False;
  Tokens := TStringList.Create;
  Emails := TStringList.Create;
  Try
    Tokens.Delimiter := #32;
    Tokens.DelimitedText := Input;
    For I := 0 To Tokens.Count - 1 Do
      begin
      Buffer := Tokens.Strings[I];
      If Length(Buffer) < 5 Then Continue;
      If (Pos('@',Buffer) > 1) And
         (Pos('.',Buffer) > 3) And
         (Pos('.',Buffer) < Length(Buffer)) Then
         begin

          Emails.Add(Buffer);
      end;
    end;
    Result := True;
  Finally
    Tokens.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure EscreveEmails;
 var
 Linhas,Emails:TStringList;
 arq: TextFile;
begin
 Linhas := TStringList.Create;
 Emails := TStringList.Create;
 try
   Linhas.LoadFromFile('foo.txt');
   AssignFile(arq, 'new.txt');
   Rewrite(arq);
      If ExtractEmails(Linhas.Text,Emails) Then
       begin
        Writeln(arq,Emails.Text);
       end;
 finally
   CloseFile(arq);
   Linhas.Free;
   Emails.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Use the `Copy` function to extract substrings an `+` to concatenate.

Comment: You'll leak `Emails` if there's an exception, and the return value is pointless, function always returns True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use a regex. I'm not a regex crack, but here is what I come with:

https://regex101.com/r/kX8yQ4/2

```
uses
  System.RegularExpressions;

function repairMailDot(const email: string): string; inline;
   begin
    result := TRegEx.Replace(email, '(@.*(?<!\.))(com(?:$|\..+))', '\1.\2', [roIgnoreCase])
   end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
    ShowMessage(repairMailDot('aaglt_assessoria@yahoocom.br'));
    ShowMessage(repairMailDot('aaglt_assessoria@yahoo.com.br'));
    ShowMessage(repairMailDot('aaglt_assessoria@yahoocom'));
    ShowMessage(repairMailDot('aaglt_assessoria@yahoo.com'));
   end;
```

Comment: You could simplify the pattern to `(@.*(?<!\.))(com(?:$|\..+))` and replace with `\1.\2`

Comment: +1 for the regex101 sandbox.  To the OP, you can add the /g flag to the example at regex101 and do a whole list of examples, hundreds of you want.  Then you'll see if there are any edge cases that you didn't consider.

Answer (score 0):

I would say first test to see if a email address is a valid email address

```
function MailURLMayBeInvalid(const s: string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
  c: string;
begin // ' ', ä, ö, ü, ß, [, ], (, ), : in EMail-Address
  Result := (Trim(s) = '') or (Pos(' ', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) or
    (Pos('ä', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) or (Pos('ö', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) or
    (Pos('ü', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) or (Pos('ß', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) or
    (Pos('[', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) or (Pos(']', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) or
    (Pos('(', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) or (Pos(')', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) or
    (Pos(':', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0);
  if Result then Exit; // @ not in EMail-Address;
  i      := Pos('@', s);
  Result := (i = 0) or (i = 1) or (i = Length(s));
  if Result then Exit;
  Result := (Pos('@', Copy(s, i + 1, Length(s) - 1)) > 0);
  if Result then Exit; // Domain <= 1
  c      := Copy(s, i + 1, Length(s));
  Result := Length(c) <= 1;
  if Result then Exit;
  i      := Pos('.', c);
  Result := (i = 0) or (i = 1) or (i = Length(c));
end;
```

if it is not a valid address then you can simply check the string for the last  occurrence of com that you can do with the `LastDelimiter` function this function should do the trick

```
function returnAddress(Address: String): String;
begin
    insert('.', Address, LastDelimiter('com',Address)-2);
    Result := Address;
end;
```